# multiple correct answers in a written excel quiz

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm doing a quiz with written answers and currently using a formula such as `=IF(D36=L36,"CORRECT","WRONG ")` 
which works for questions with a single correct answer.

For some questions there are 2 or possibly 3 correct answers but I can't seem to expand the formula to include more than one option for a correct answer.

I tried expanding the subset
`=IF(F36=(M36,M37),"CORRECT","WRONG ")`
but it doesn't work

and tried using an OR function
=IF(OR(F36=(M36,M37)),"CORRECT","WRONG ")
But that doesn't work either.

Any help as to how to fix this without rewriting my existing formula too much?

Comment: That's not correct syntax for the `OR()` function. Please read about it in the ms-documentation.

Comment: OR(F36=M36,F36=M37) but you could use vlookup() - check that out.

Answer (score 1):

### Use MATCH for an Excel Quiz

- If the answers are in the same row as the question...

[image]

```
=IF(C2="","No Answer",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,L2:O2,0)),"Correct","Wrong"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(OR(addr1=addr2,addr3=addr4,addr5=addr6),"CORRECT","WRONG")
```

This means CORRECT if any one (or more) of the 3 comparisons are TRUE

You would use AND() if CORRECT means all three comparisons are TRUE